# Sharing a session between Ruby and PHP

Tags: php, ruby, single-sign-on, subdomain

Is it possible to share a session between my PHP app on a subdomain and my Ruby apps on my other subdomains?

I don't really know where to take it from here. I know I can manually set the domain to the root one so that the cookie is valid for all the subdomains, but how would I get/set stuff from/to the session so that it's shared across the subdomains?

I mainly want to use this to share login for my whole subdomains.

For the sake of knowledge, if it is the wrong approach to the problem, albeit a doable one, I'd like to understand both how to do it, and why should I not.

Thank you all!

Comment: Very late to the party, but I have run into this problem myself recently and have posted a Rails PHP-combatible session store on my blog (it should be easy enough to adapt the principles to a non-Rails app): http://watsonbox.github.com/blog/2012/05/01/sharing-session-between-rails-and-php/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to share sessions in that manner (accross PHP/Java/Ruby/etc), you need to save sessions (and access them) from a Database.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

And you would need an identical approach in Ruby.

To share cookies across domains, you also need to change the PHP session configuration option for `session.cookie_domain` from the default of `""` (which inserts your domain name) to: `".yourhost.com"` (note the prefixed period).

Answer (score 2):

This could be solved with apps sharing the same database and with a little help of cookies.

- Session opened in php

  - Create a cookie with random string in it
  - Save the string in database with user credentials and timestamp
- Session forwarded to rails

  - Check if the cookie exists
  - Search the string in cookie form the database
  - If match is found, then session is accepted and the same user credentials could be used

It would be wise to store some kind of unique information of the workstation or the browser, so that stealing the session, with copying the cookie wont work.

Comment: What kind of unique info should I store? And what kind of random string should I generate? If I hashed together some information about the host, would it be "safe enough"? Like, a MD5 hash containing the remote host and remote address? With that I could "match" the info on the server side... Help? :P

Comment: You got it right. Unique information could be MD5 hash (even better if it is SHA) of remote host ip + user agent row from http header + a salt.