# Is it possible to access php $_SESSION variables in a cgi/ruby script?

Tags: php, ruby

Title pretty much speaks for itself.  Is there a simple way to do this?  I was thinking of just writing the data stored in the session variable to a temp file then having the ruby script read the data from the file, but that seems kind of dumb.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well, that's exactly how PHP sessions work by default: using temp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems to have been already addressed: [Sharing a session between Ruby and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097451/sharing-a-session-between-ruby-and-php#answer-3097512)

Comment: I saw that thread and was hoping there was a simpler way, but it doesn't sound like there is...  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the cleanest mechanism would be to write a custom PHP session handler that:

- Stores data to a database (rather than files)
- Serializes data to a format known by Ruby, possibly JSON